# Extend the social_auth User model in Django

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm using Django-social-auth for the first time, and it seems that all the new users are registered in the User's model of the social_auth app of my Django website. I have a different model called Users which has some specific data (related to the users activity in the site and relation with other entities) and I want to put the data fetched from users' Facebook profiles (username, profile picture etc) into the Users model that I made myself. is there any way to extend the social_auth Users?

**EDIT**
After reading the Django-social-auth documentation, i edited my User class as follow :

```
# User model
```

class User(models.Model):

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
playedHours = models.FloatField(default = 0)


userSlug = models.SlugField(unique = True)    

playedSongs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, blank=True, null = True)
invitedFriends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank = True, null = True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Also, how can i get the user's profile picture, friends list and so on?
I dont understand the mechanism of this.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a custom Manager class as required, and called it `CustomUserManager`.

Here is the code:

```
class CustomUserManager(models.Manager):
    def create_user(self, username, email):
        return self.model._default_manager.create(username=username)
```

then I changed my User class to:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    playedHours = models.FloatField(default = 0)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    playedSongs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, blank=True, null = True)
    invitedFriends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank = True, null = True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username

def is_authenticated(self):
    return True
```

In my settings.py :

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myappname.User'
```

Thanks ArgsKwargs for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

from the docs:

> It's possible to override the used User model if needed:
>
> `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'`

source: [github](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth#custom-user-model)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to proceed. I can't find the create_user() method. How can I add the Model Manager and the create_user method ? Sorry, this is my first time with Django-social-auth